# How to bind data in html table in asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind data and display table record in Html table in asp.net web form,
Using any method like foreach and for loop,

Like if you aware about this,  That we can import namespace and and using class we can define datasource and getting ds variable in .Aspx page.

Same like in asp.net mvc, We are directly bind data in lable, textbox.

So thought by this way i want to doing speedlly data communication to database.

Please help me and given appropriate response of this question.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aslam,

Yes you can declare a public variable/property in your `aspx.cs` class. You can assign that variable/property in Page_Load or any other appropriate event and then you can directly access it in your aspx.

following is the example:

```
public DataSet ds;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    //load your ds from database
}
```

Following is the code to use table 0 from database to create table in aspx

```
<table>
<% foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) { %>
<tr>
<td><%= row["columnName"] %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

Hope this helps