# Getting value from last row of SQL Server database C#

Tags: c#

```
    public queue getQueueDataByID(int queueID)
    {


         string DBConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;

         SqlDataAdapter da;
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         queue myQueue = new queue();

         StringBuilder sqlCommand = new StringBuilder();
         sqlCommand.AppendLine("Select * from QueueTable where");
         sqlCommand.AppendLine("id = @paraId");

        try
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);

            // sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("paraCustId", tbCustId.Text);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand.ToString(), myConn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("paraId", queueID);
            // fill dataset
            da.Fill(ds, "QueueTable");
            //conn.Close();
            int rec_cnt = ds.Tables["QueueTable"].Rows.Count;
            DataRow row = ds.Tables["QueueTable"].Rows[rec_cnt-1 ];
            myQueue.queueNo = row["QueueNo"].ToString();
            myQueue.NRIC = row["NRIC"].ToString();
            myQueue.ContactNo = row["ContactNo"].ToString();

                }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

        }
        return myQueue;
    }
```

This is my class,I am trying to retrieve the datas from the last row of the database to display in a web form, any idea how i can do that? My "id", primary key is set as autoincrement.

Comment: does this code throws exception or doesn't return last row?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, the main point is, i have no idea how to retrieve, or more like, i dont know what code to use in my web form to retrieve.

Comment: for that you need to bind this queue to web-form fields.Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800566/how-to-bind-data-in-html-table-in-asp-net-web-form

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq on the datatable to get the last row.

```
 var queueDataTable = ds.Tables[0];
 var lastDataRow = queueDataTable.AsEnumerable().Last();
```

If you need to itterate through all the rows in the datatable

```
foreach (var dataRow in queueDataTable.AsEnumerable())
{

}
```

thanks

Comment: Hi thank you for replying

This may sound stupid but where should i put the code

Comment: No problem. You need to encapsulate the database access code in a datalayer class if not done already with a public method that returns the dataset or datatable. This should be referenced and called by a service/bunsiness layer which acts upon the data returned to get the last row and populate your Queue object to finally return it to your calling web method.  Your moving into the realms of design though which is not for discussion here.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!